# take output from the mysql and stored into excel

Tags: command-line, scripts, mysql

i have database under that one table. for eg test_table. in that

```
  name age sex edu   job    timein              doj
  yyy   33  m   bsc  comp   22/3/13 12:32:44    3/2/11
  xxx   22  f   mca  soft   22/3/13 11:30:11    11/10/09
  zzz   44  f   puc  clerk  22/3/13 12:00:24    5/11/08
```

command

```
 mysql -u root -ppass123  -e "use test_db; select name,age, sex,edu,job,timein,doj from test_table;"
```

how to convert into excel

Comment: Can't you use the [SELECT... INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) syntax to create a CSV file directly?

Comment: @steeldriver : how to use. I'm a new one in this mysql

Comment: Move to the directory where you would like to save your ("excel") file using cd. Then run mysql -u root -ppass123  -e "use test_db; select * into outfile 'testtable.csv' from test_table;". It will produce a file called testtable.csv in this directory, that you can probably open with excel/libreOffice Look into this link for more specific info on how to use select ... into outfile: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Save in CSV format then import the CSV file to excel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: @Gasp0de Would you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @ByteCommander did that =)

Answer (score 6):

Move to the directory where you would later like to have your CSV file saved. Then run

```
mysql -u root -ppass123 -e "USE test_db; SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'testtable.csv' FROM test_table;"
```

Please note that "SELECT *" selects all columns, while you listed all of them. If you want to select only certain columns, you will need to replace * by the columns names again, separated by commas.

It will produce a file called `testtable.csv` in this directory, that you can open with *MS Excel* or *LibreOffice Calc*.

Look into the MySQL documentation for `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` here for further info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be storing the output directly in a `.xls` spreadsheet;

That can be done by piping the output of `mysql` to `ssconvert` (in the `gnumeric` package), but requires `ssconvert`'s input file to be either a CSV or a TSV.

So you could add the `-B` option to the `mysql` command (which forces `mysql` to output a TSV) and pipe the output of the `mysql` command to `ssconvert`:

```bsh
mysql -u root -ppass123  -B -e "use test_db; select name,age, sex,edu,job,timein,doj from test_table;" |\
ssconvert fd://0 output_file.xls
```

Comment: i need to add a output to file on 6th column. how can i do

Comment: @user476625 Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify? You want 5 empty columns before the first one? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/743356/edit) your question adding an example.